# replace only strings that are nested beside non-numbers

Tags: bash, sed

I am using the following bash code using sed to replace all instances of "600" with "123" in a HTML file:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/'\"600\"'/'\"123\"'/' index.html
```

I would like to extend the search to target not only instances of 600 in quotes, but any non-numeric character.

For example -600-,  600 , ^600^ would be targeted, but 16001, -6001, 1600-, would not be.

Comment: Is it Mac OS sed? Try word boundaries: `sed -i '' -e 's/[[:<:]]600[[:>:]]/123/g' index.html`. If it is a GNU sed, ``sed -i 's/\b600\b/123/g' index.html`` should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's Mac OS, and this works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the prefix and suffix using groups. `[^0-9]` matches non-numeric characters.

```
sed -i '' -E 's,([^0-9])600([^0-9]),\1123\2,g' index.html
```

Example :

```
a600a
^600^
16001
600
```

becomes

```
a123a
^123^
16001
600
```

You can also use this to fix the last line (600 has no prefix/suffix) :

```
sed -i '' -E 's,([^0-9]|^)600([^0-9]|$),\1123\2,g' index.html
```

Result :

```
a123a
^123^
16001
123
```

Comment: The first line of code you posted doesn't work if I put a tab in front of the 600, then a newline immediately afterwards like:

 600

However, your 2nd line of code works a treat, thanks